# Login to OpenERP using LDAP

Tags: ldap, odoo

I am using OpenERP for my company, and I'm trying to log in using LDAP.

I downloaded the ldap_auth plugin, and configured my company's settings.

After I configured, I logged out as an administrator and tried to log in using LDAP settings, but with no success.

> "Username or Password is Wrong".

I want the user to write his E-Mail on the "User" field, and his Password on the "Password" field. But I don't know how to do this.

EDIT: I have python-ldap 2.7 installed.

Here are my settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the "Filtro LDAP" field to the appropriate email field on your LDAP tree, so where you have "AMAccountName=%s" you should have "wtv_name_of_field_you_want_to_check_in_your_LDAP_tree=%s".

Since you have the "Criar utilizador" checked, you have to select a default user in the "Utilizador modelo" dropdown, users that authenticate sucessfully on LDAP will be created on OpenERP db with the same access rights as that default user.

Also, if your server allows anonymous binding, you don't need to fill the "Senha LDAP" field, since you are not going to make changes on LDAP side.

---

You might want to populate your users and store them in your OpenERP database, for that you'll need to install the "LDAP Populate" module, I advice you to install also the "LDAP mapping for user name and e-mail" in order to map and store users real (full) name and email.

And finaly, note that you can have users that authenticate locally (e.g. admin user) and users that authenticate in LDAP. LDAP is queried after the local database and only when local authentication fails.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I did everything you told me, but it still says "Wrong Username of Password" when i try to log in.

Comment: Make sure that OpenERP is able to connect to your ldap through that address "bpt.kme.intern".

Comment: Talk to your sysadmin and make sure that from the ip of your OpenERP server you can resolve that address. If not, ask him what is your ldap server public address and configure that address instead. He'll know what to do to allow the two machines to communicate :-)